# How to use log4j to log different package's message into same log file?

Tags: java, log4j

I am the beginner using log4j, please don't mind my stupid questions.

Now I have a jar contain some methods I would use in different classes. Let say a calculator method. This method has a several messages and exception handling that need to log.

I have two classes that need to use this method for calculation and these two classes have their own log file. classA.log and classB.log

The question is how to log the message and error that came from the calculator in to classA.log and classB.log depends on which class is calling calculator.

I want the classA.log and classB.log like:

```
[datetime] INFO - [foo.A] This is class A
[datetime] INFO - [foo.A] Now calling calculator
[datetime] INFO - [cal.mycal.Calculator] Now enter calculator and start calculating
[datetime] WARN - [cal.mycal.Calculator] A warning message from calculator
[datetime] ERROR - [cal.mycal.Calculator] An error message from calculator
[datetime] INFO - [foo.A] Some mistakes are made.
[datetime] INFO - [foo.A] Class A done
```

In log4j.xml, I need to add a logger and ref to which class I need to log

```
  <logger name="foo.A">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="A" />
  </logger> 
  <logger name="cal.mycal.Calculator">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="A" />
  </logger>
```

and the appender

```
  <appender name="A" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="log/classA.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"></param>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] %-5p - [%c] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

But after doing this, method call from foo.B won't write to classB.log. All message from Calculator write to classA.log

How I get the logger:

```
protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

Can I have some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You set the file name value "classA.log" in this line. <param name="File" value="log/classA.log"/>. You need to set "classB.log" separately.

Comment: I need to have separate file classA.log and classB.log both can log the message from Calculator. After I set values="log/classB.log", The message would log to classB.log. After foo.A call Calculator's method. The message would log to wrong location i.e classB.log

Comment: That's when foo.A call Calculator's methods, the message would log to classA.log, foo.B call, message would log to classB.log

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are starting to append the contents into the log files.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you tried multiple appenders and adding them to "root" tag?